# Is there a way to set a login timeout by firewall on symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security, symfony5

I need to be able to set a different login timeout for each firewall I have.

How can I do this? I can only set the cookie lifetime for the entire app, not only for the part handled by the social firewall. Also, I can't find any documentation to separate cookie lifetime by firewall. Is there another way to do so?

I'm using `PdoSessionHandler` as the session handler:

`App\Config\Package\security.yaml`:

```yaml
security:
    # ... #
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        api:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: social_user_provider
            pattern: ^/app

            logout:
                path: social_logout
                target: social_redirect_after_logout

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernal.secret'
                lifetime: 3600 # 1 hour
                path:     /

        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: app_login

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

        # ... #
```

`App\Config\services.yaml`:

```yaml
services:

    # ... #
    # Sessions handler
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - 'mysql:dbname=%env(resolve:DATABASE_NAME)%; host=%env(resolve:DATABASE_HOST)%; port=%env(resolve:DATABASE_PORT)%'
            - { db_username: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_USER)%', db_password: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_PASSWORD)%' }
```

`App\Config\Packages\framework.yaml`

```yaml
framework:
    # ... #
    session:
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i would do it:

Create custom classes overriding the GuardAuthenticators, like:

`MyApiFirewallGuard extends App\Security\TokenAuthenticator`

`MyMainFirewallGuard extends App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator`

etc.

Then, use these classes in your security.yaml file, you may also have to register them as services to make sure they receive correct construction params.

Now in the docs you can see a bit about manual authentication:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#manually-authenticating-a-user

This part is interesting:

```
public function supports(Request $request)
    {
+         // if there is already an authenticated user (likely due to the session)
+         // then return false and skip authentication: there is no need.
+         if ($this->security->getUser()) {
+             return false;
+         }

+         // the user is not logged in, so the authenticator should continue
+         return true;
    }
```

Here, you have a session and thus you can do your own session timeout logic. There might be other hooks/places inside the overridden GuardAuthenticators that also allow to further alter the behaviour to what you need.

Comment: Interesting but I was thinking of a more integrating way in symfony, like in config files or in a voter. Can you provide a way to change the timeout with your way?